# How to specify "MainLayout" in a sub Layout in razor class library

Tags: blazor

If you use a sub Layout you need to specify the MainLayout the app uses in most cases it is `MainLayout.razor`.

`ChatPageLayout.razor` in a separate DLL.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@layout MainLayout  <---- How to specify what consumer uses
<ChatRoom RoomName="TestRoom" >
    <ChatNav />
    @body
</ ChatRoom>
```

How do I specify or provide the value type of the layout the consumer of the library uses.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what your question is, so here are several answers dependant on the true meaning of the question.

If you just want to reference a `Layout` in another library, then add the reference to the project and either reference it fully or add a @namespace to `_Import.razor`.

```
@layout Blazor.Starter.Shared.MainLayout
```

If you want to change it at runtime, then you can't using the out-of-the-box code.  The layout for a page is set as an attribute at compile time.  `@layout` becomes

```cs
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.LayoutAttribute(typeof(MainLayout))]
    public partial class Index : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase
```

The layout, and all content, is rendered by the `RouteView` component.  You can change the default here, but if you want to manage layouts runtime, then you will need to write a new `RouteView`.

```cs
// App.razor
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Comment: I want to make a NuGet package that includes this sublayout. It seems that you have to specify the parent layout in the child layout.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by sublayout?  In out-of-the-box Razor there's one layout per page/routeview, either the default layout spec'd in `App` or the one defined in the individual page through `@Layout`.

Comment: A nested layout some people call it. There are plenty examples of how. In fact it worked before I tried to refactor the code out into a library for packaging

Comment: In your code where is `MainLayout`?  It must be in the same, or a referenced library from where `ChatPageLayout ` lives.  The Layout Attribute on `ChatPageLayout` is set at compile time as I showed you above.  That's why it worked before you refactored your code.